# automate activecell values and offset function

Tags: excel, vba, offset

'Please help me to automate the below code using input function, so that i can just type the number in the input box to get desired rows to be filled automatically.'

```
sub DAY()
GENERAL Macro


ActiveCell.Value = "DAY"

Select Case ActiveCell.Value

Case "DAY"
    ActiveCell.Resize(, 1).Value = "DAY"
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Value = "OFF"
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 2).Value = "DAY"
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 3).Value = "OFF"
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 4).Value = "DAY"
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 5).Value = "OFF"
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 6).Value = "DAY"
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 7).Value = "OFF"
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 8).Value = "DAY"
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 9).Value = "OFF"
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 10).Value = "DAY"
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 11).Value = "OFF"
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 12).Value = "DAY"
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 13).Value = "OFF"


 End Select

 End Sub
```

'Please help me to automate the below code using input function, so that i can just type the number in the input box to get desired rows to be filled automatically.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use formulas

```
Sub Day()
    Dim n As Long
    n = CLng(InputBox("How many days?"))
    With ActiveCell.Resize(1, 2 * n)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=""DAY"",""OFF"",""DAY"")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but it is filling row wise, i would like to get it column wise.

Comment: @mahesh, edited code to write column wise. If this answers your question, you may want to mark it as accepted. Thank you

Comment: Nice way to do it. Can you force it to always start with the word "Day" though?

Comment: @CLR, thanks. And yes, I can: for instance adding an IF … Then…Else to either handle two formulas or set two strings to be used in the formula. Or changing the formula to query the preceeding cell value being “DAY” or not

Comment: this formula throws #NAME? ERROR

Comment: @mahesh; sorry, mispelled the COLUMN() worksheet function for "COL". Edited the solution

Comment: @mahesh, edited again right now to have it always starting with "DAY"

Comment: tried the latest code and it show .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]=""DAY"","OFF"",""DAY"")" Syntax error....

Comment: @mahesh, there was a misisng quotation mark: edited

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want something like this?

```
Sub PopulateListByRows()
    Dim n As Long, a As Long, ArrTxt
    n = InputBox("How many days?")
    ArrTxt = Array("Day", "Off")
    For a = 1 To n
        ActiveCell.Offset(a - 1).Value = ArrTxt((a + 1) Mod 2)
    Next
End Sub

Sub PopulateListByColumns()
    Dim n As Long, a As Long, ArrTxt
    n = InputBox("How many days?")
    ArrTxt = Array("Day", "Off")
    For a = 1 To n
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, a - 1).Value = ArrTxt((a + 1) Mod 2)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. This code writes the DAY and OFF in next following rows.  I want it to be in next columns. please help.

Comment: I've created a second version for columns.

Comment: This code works perfectly thanks